# jquery ajax json rpc how to retrieve data on server

Tags: jquery, ajax, json-rpc

I'm getting headache on how retrieving my data server side from an jquery/ajax/json rpc call !

Here is the client side :

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: 'http://wine-trip.net/php/ajax/setVinImage.php',
        data: JSON.stringify({jsonrpc:'2.0',method:'add',params:[{'vigneronID':'14818','action':'deleteImage','vinID':'13','vinImageType':'Bouteille'}],id:"jsonrpc"}),
        dataType:"json", 
        success:function(data){
            if (typeof (data.error.message) === 'undefined') { 
                // Everything was OK 
            }
            else{
                alert(data.error.message);
            }               
        },
        error: function(req) {
            alert("Networking problem");
        }
    });
```

and here is the begin of the server-side :

```
// HTTP headers for no cache etc
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

error_log("POST ".$_POST['vigneronID'], 0);
error_log("REQUEST ".$_REQUEST['vigneronID'], 0);
```

I get answer from server displaying in alert but can't acces the data I'm passing throught the params (bad syntax ?).

I could do a normal ajax call but since I'm using plupload library (which works with json rpc), I'd like to figure out why I can't use this method !

I've tried with or without the contentType but doesn't seem to change anything ...

Answer (score 0):

im guessing that error_log sends out some strings?  it helps to use json_encode
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php.  i would also recommend using developer tools such as firebug for firefox, you can see what your server sends out